# Python multiprocessing pipe and cloudpickle

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I have observed that this code can't run on windows, it seems that the PipeConnection handles can't be copied 1:1 so I asume that multiprocessing lib does some kind of extra work when dealing with Process args of type PipeConnection. This is a toy example of the problem:

```
import multiprocessing, cloudpickle

def _thunk(pipe):
    def f():
        test = pipe[1].recv()
        pipe[1].send(test)

    return f


def _worker(pickled_f):
    f = cloudpickle.loads(pickled_f)
    f()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    pipe = multiprocessing.Pipe()

    pickled_f = cloudpickle.dumps(_thunk(pipe))
    multiprocessing.Process(target=_worker, args=(pickled_f,)).start()

    pipe[0].send('test')
    test = pipe[0].recv()

    print(test)
```

I want to get around this but I can't modify the multiprocessing.Process call, because it is in a lib outside of my code. Other synchronization mechanisms are welcome as long as I can encapsulate the logic inside the thunk. But ideally I want to be able to reconstruct a working Pipe in my new process.

Thanks.